# Remove duplicates from training set for classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, logistic, stratification

Let us say I have a bunch of rows for a classification problem:

$$X_1, ... X_N, Y$$

Where $X_1, ..., X_N$ are the features/predictors and $Y$ is the class the row’s feature combination belongs to.

Many feature combination and their classes are repeated in the dataset, which I am using to fit a classifier. I am just wondering if it is acceptable to remove duplicates (I basically perform a `group by X1 ... XN Y` in SQL)? Thanks.

PS:

This is for a binary presence only dataset where the class priors are quite skewed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is not acceptable. The repetitions are what provide the weight of the evidence.

If you remove your duplicates, a four-leaf clover is as significant as a regular, three-leaf clover, since each will occur once, whereas in real life there is a four-leaf clover for every 10,000 regular clovers.

Even if your priors are "quite skewed", as you say, the purpose of the training set is to accumulate real-life experience, which you will not achieve if you lose the frequency information.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer but here are my reservations. It is advisable to remove duplicates while segregating samples for training and testing for **specific classifiers** such as Decision Trees. Say, 20% of your data belonged to a particular class and $\frac{1}{4}^{th}$ of those seeped into testing, then algorithms such as Decision Trees will create *gateways* to that class with the duplicate samples. This could provide misleading results on the test set because essentially there is a very specific *gateway* to the correct output.

When you deploy that classifier to completely new data, it could perform astonishingly poor if there are no samples similar to the above said 20% samples.

**Argument**: One may argue that this situation points to a flawed dataset but I think this is true to real life applications.

Removing duplicates for Neural Networks, Bayesian models etc is not acceptable.

Comment: Another feasible solution could be to weight the duplicates lower based on their frequency of occurrence.

Comment: `Say, 20% of your data belonged to a particular class and 1/4th of those seeped into testing, then algorithms such as Decision Trees will create gateways to that class with the duplicate samples.` So basically you are saying that keeping duplicates might lead to data leakage? If so then this is true for all algo's not just decision trees